# NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS Graphic card issue - the screen splits into 6 parts

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, hp-pavilion

I receive display error while switching on the computer (HP Pavilion dv6670ec).

> The screen splits into 6 parts (6 same small displays within my screen)

The error appears just while starting the computer.

> 1. I tried to reinstall graphic card drivers (NVidia 8400 GS), but received the error message, that it's not possible to install (current max resolution is just 800x600)
> 2. I also tried external display (through VGA) - no response
> 3. I tried system repair - no result

BIOS doesn't show any graphic card information.
After system repair, I'm not able to see anything when logged in Windows (I see just initial process on the screen)

Any suggestions what could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: So in the BIOS, the screen looks OK? it looks like you are using windows (please include the OS and version in your question), can you start in Safe Mode? does the problem still occur there?

Comment: The problem occures everywhere - also BIOS is splitted, all initial screens (HP initial screen also) are splitted. I'm running on Win7.

Comment: Umm if you see this problem in the BIOS, it sounds like a hardware thing. Sounds like you will have to take it to be fixed...

Comment: Do you think the graphic card could be burned out?

Comment: Don't really know, something is wrong either with your graphics card or with your monitor.

Comment: ok, thank you, it seems on the hardware issue also to me.

Comment: I swear the 8xxx series has the BEST failure modes. They had a design flaw, and the two of that family I had died differently. You're probably best off getting a new graphics card if you can

Comment: on external display, did you do the "Fn" key and whatever f# the screen icon has? my acer is Fn+F5.

Comment: yes, no response

Comment: I'm afraid buying new one would be more expensive than buy brand new notebook